# How to downsample a Pandas DataFrame 8 times when having numeric and non-numeric data?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

I have the following dataframe:

| Index | AccX | AccY | AccZ | EDA | Hour | Label | Minute | Second | Subject | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.78 | -0.86 | -0.10 | 0.016 | 13.0 | Relax1 | 13.0 | 40.000 | Subject1 | 2017-03-22 13:13:40.000 |
| 1 | 0.77 | -0.87 | -0.03 | 0.014 | 13.0 | Relax1 | 13.0 | 40.125 | Subject1 | 2017-03-22 13:13:40.125 |
| 2 | 0.77 | -0.87 | -0.04 | 0.016 | 13.0 | Relax1 | 13.0 | 40.250 | Subject1 | 2017-03-22 13:13:40.250 |
| ... | .... | .... | .... | ... | .... | ..... | ...... | ...... | ....... | .... |
| 8 | 0.77 | -0.87 | -0.03 | 0.014 | 13.0 | Relax1 | 13.0 | 41.000 | Subject1 | 2017-03-22 13:13:41.000 |

And I want to downsample it 8 times based on column Second, without so it should look like this:

| Index | AccX | AccY | AccZ | EDA | Hour | Label | Minute | Second | Subject | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.78 | -0.86 | -0.10 | 0.016 | 13.0 | Relax1 | 13.0 | 40.000 | Subject1 | 2017-03-22 13:13:40.000 |
| 1 | 0.77 | -0.87 | -0.03 | 0.014 | 13.0 | Relax1 | 13.0 | 41.000 | Subject1 | 2017-03-22 13:13:41.000 |
| ... | .... | .... | .... | ... | .... | ..... | ...... | ...... | ....... | .... |

I have tried the above script:

```
data['DateTime']= pd.to_datetime(data['DateTime'])
data_resampled = data.groupby(['Subject', 'Label']).resample('8S', on='DateTime').mean()
data_resampled
```

but it does not work. Do you have any suggestions on how to get the proper results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) to select between *numeric* and *non-numeric* columns and pass a dictionary to [`aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) those columns using distinct functions.

*Sample data*

```py
     Index   AccX  AccY  AccZ    EDA Hour   Label Minute     Second   Subject                DateTime
0         0  0.78 -0.86 -0.10  0.016   13  Relax1     13  40.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:40.000
1         1  0.77 -0.87 -0.03  0.014   13  Relax1     13  40.125000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:40.125
2         2  0.77 -0.87 -0.04  0.016   13  Relax1     13  40.250000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:40.250
..      ...   ...   ...   ...    ...  ...     ...    ...        ...       ...                     ...
297       0  0.78 -0.86 -0.10  0.016   13  Relax1     14  17.125000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:14:17.125
298       1  0.77 -0.87 -0.03  0.014   13  Relax1     14  17.250000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:14:17.250
299       2  0.77 -0.87 -0.04  0.016   13  Relax1     14  17.375000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:14:17.375

[300 rows x 11 columns]
```

```py
cols = data.columns  # keep columns order

numeric = data.select_dtypes(include='number').columns
non_num = data.select_dtypes(exclude=['number']).columns

agg_dict = {**{x: 'mean' for x in numeric}, **{x: 'first' for x in non_num}}

# You can also handpick certain columns by name
agg_dict.update({
  'Second': 'first',
  'Minute': 'first',
  'Hour'  : 'first',
})

data_resampled = data.resample('1S', on='DateTime').agg(agg_dict).reset_index(drop=True)
data_resampled = data_resampled[cols] # set original columns order
print(data_resampled)
```

Output *data_resampled*

```py
    Index   AccX  AccY  AccZ   EDA Hour   Label Minute     Second   Subject            DateTime
0    0.875  0.77 -0.87 -0.06  0.02   13  Relax1     13  40.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:40
1    1.000  0.77 -0.87 -0.06  0.02   13  Relax1     13  41.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:41
2    1.125  0.77 -0.87 -0.05  0.02   13  Relax1     13  42.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:42
3    0.875  0.77 -0.87 -0.06  0.02   13  Relax1     13  43.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:43
4    1.000  0.77 -0.87 -0.06  0.02   13  Relax1     13  44.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:13:44
..     ...   ...   ...   ...   ...  ...     ...    ...        ...       ...                 ...
34   1.000  0.77 -0.87 -0.06  0.02   13  Relax1     14  14.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:14:14
35   1.125  0.77 -0.87 -0.05  0.02   13  Relax1     14  15.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:14:15
36   0.875  0.77 -0.87 -0.06  0.02   13  Relax1     14  16.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:14:16
37   1.250  0.77 -0.87 -0.05  0.02   13  Relax1     14  17.000000  Subject1 2017-03-22 13:14:17
```